# Cargo package conflicts

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm having a hard time getting all these deps to play nicely together

```
[dependencies]
esp-idf-hal = "0.42.0"
esp-idf-svc = "0.42.0"
esp-idf-sys = "0.34.5"
smart-leds = "0.4.0"
smart-leds-trait = "0.3.0"
ws2812-esp32-rmt-driver = "0.7.1"
```

```
error: failed to select a version for `embedded-hal`.
    ... required by package `esp-idf-hal v0.38.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `esp-idf-hal = "^0.38"` of package `esp-idf-svc v0.42.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `esp-idf-svc = "^0.42"` of package `cardputer v0.1.0 (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/rustification/cardputer)`
versions that meet the requirements `=1.0.0-alpha.8` are: 1.0.0-alpha.8

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `embedded-hal v1.0.0-rc.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `embedded-hal = "=1.0.0-rc.1"` of package `esp-idf-hal v0.42.5`
    ... which satisfies dependency `esp-idf-hal = "^0.42"` of package `cardputer v0.1.0 (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/rustification/cardputer)`

failed to select a version for `embedded-hal` which could resolve this conflict
```

and

```
error: failed to select a version for `esp-idf-hal`.
    ... required by package `ws2812-esp32-rmt-driver v0.7.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ws2812-esp32-rmt-driver = "^0.7.1"` of package `cardputer v0.1.0 (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/rustification/cardputer)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.42` are: 0.42.5

the package `esp-idf-hal` links to the native library `esp_idf_hal`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `esp_idf_hal` as well:
package `esp-idf-hal v0.43.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `esp-idf-hal = "^0.43.0"` of package `cardputer v0.1.0 (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/rustification/cardputer)`
Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the `links = "esp_idf_hal"` value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.

failed to select a version for `esp-idf-hal` which could resolve this conflict
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears like `ws2812-esp32-rmt-driver` is locked on `esp-idf-sys` version 0.42, which means you'll have to either wait for their devs to upgrade the dependency, or use older versions.

As far as I can tell, the following does not have any conflicts, but includes some older package versions:

```ini
[dependencies]
esp-idf-hal = "0.42.0"
esp-idf-svc = "^0.47"
esp-idf-sys = "^0.33"
smart-leds = "0.4.0"
smart-leds-trait = "0.3.0"
ws2812-esp32-rmt-driver = "0.7.1"
```